# Blob indexer does not work with Azure Search service

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I went through all steps posted on the following page carefully using POSTMAN tool and also C# to create index, blob data source, container and indexer:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage/

I am 100% sure that all components were created successfully. I verified them all through Azure resource management portal. I uploaded two word documents to the container as two blobs and executed the indexer manually using Azure portal and also by POSTMAN. The status shows success but none of the documents indexed! The portal shows 0/0 documents.

Comment: Please email me your search service name and indexer name and the time when you set it up. My email is eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain.

Comment: Arash - as written, it's unclear what you're asking or what your issue is. You haven't shown anything you've done, only posted that you're "100% sure" everything is correct (yet things aren't working). I suggest editing your question to show how you set things up, including how you're indexing. Otherwise there's simply no way to attempt to answer.

Comment: David, if you reiterate my question again you will realize that I mentioned I executed every single step explained in the link I posted from Azure website. Didn't I? That article does not make a PoC work and I will explain why shortly.

Answer (score 4):

The root cause of not being able to have Azure Search Service index blobs in a container is due to having "query" entry for "container" definition. I removed it from the API calls and the documents started being picked up and processed.

```
POST https://[service name].search.windows.net/datasources?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview
Content-Type: application/json
api-key: [admin key]

{
    "name" : "blob-datasource",
    "type" : "azureblob",
    "credentials" : { "connectionString" : "<my storage connection string>" },
    "container" : { "name" : "my-container", "query" : "my-folder" }
}
```

Comment: The article explains that the `query` parameter is optional, and tries to explain that it refers to a virtual blob folder, and value needs to be replaced with something that corresponds to your actual container layout. I’ll see if we can make the wording clearer. Thanks!